# Jboss runtime error "Worker Thread Initialization Failure"

Tags: jboss

I got "Worker Thread Initialization Failure +jboss-4.2.2.GA" error in My production server.What is solution to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because remoting is enabled in Jboss.
If we disable the remoting hopefully that should solve the problem.